# Vb6: Separating Tab Delimited Text

Tags: parsing, vb6, csv

I have a file with several thousand rows and several columns separated with tabs What I'd like to do is loop through each individually, Drop the columns into an array so that I can place them in another application individually, then move onto the next line.  Unfortunately I got about as far as this:

```
Open mytextfile.txt For Input As #FileHandle
 Do While Not EOF(FileHandle)
 Line Input #FileHandle, IndividualLine
 StringToBreakup = IndividualLine
Loop
```

So how would I go about breaking individual line up into an array

Answer (score 7):

```
Dim str() as String

Open mytextfile.txt For Input As #FileHandle
    Do While Not EOF(FileHandle)
    Line Input #FileHandle, IndividualLine
    str = Split(IndividualLine, vbTab)
    Debug.Print str(0)  'First array element
Loop
```

To clarify: I would avoid the use of Variants and use vbTab.

Answer (score 0):

Use the split command

```
Dim StringArray as Variant

Open mytextfile.txt For Input As #FileHandle
 Do While Not EOF(FileHandle)
 Line Input #FileHandle, IndividualLine
 StringToBreakup = IndividualLine

 StringArray = Split(StringToBreakup, CHR(9)) 

 Process array here...

Loop
```